Подводный камень интерполяции строк
Рассмотрим строку:
"{0} Client called server Method: {1}) Returned: {2} Status: {3}.", 
                    session.GetClientInfo(), request, response, status

$"{session.GetClientInfo()} Client called server Method: {request}) Returned: {response} Status: {status}."

Оказывается, что в request, response, status может оказаться какая-либо пара (а может и одинарная, не проверял) фигурных скобок. В этом случае повторное форматирование может привести к ошибкам.
Когда это происходит? Например если у нас есть функция типа этой:
static void outMessage(LogFilter type, LogLevel level, string text, params object[] args)
{
    Logger logger = GetLoggerByType(type);
    logger.write(new LogMessage(level, type, string.Format(text, args)));
}

Если в качестве аргумента будет строка с фигурными скобками, внутри которых есть выражение с неопознаваемым форматом, например:

{{ "useBindlessRpc": true, "meteringLevel": "METERING_LEVEL_LEGACY", "clientSdkInfo": { "sdkName": "BGS C++ SDK", "sdkVersion": { "majorVersion": 6, "minorVersion": 2, "patchVersion": 0, "versionString": "6.2.0" }, "protocolVersion": { "majorVersion": 3, "minorVersion": 11, "patchVersion": 10, "versionString": "3.11.10-44dad063b5" } } }}

То вы можете получить ошибку:

Почему такая функция существует вообще:

Наверное создавалась во времена, до введения интерполяции
Поддержка обоих вариантов
Возможно предполагалась поддержка комбинированного варианта (не очень хорошая идея, потому как в этом случае ошибки точно не избежать)

Откуда могут взяться фигурные скобки в переменной:

Ввод с клавиатуры
результат сериализации
из любого другого места

Также возможно проблема может возникнуть из-за этого при наличии внутри скобок:
Prior to C# 10, if an interpolated string has the type string, it's typically transformed into a String.Format method call. The compiler may replace String.Format with String.Concat if the analyzed behavior would be equivalent to concatenation.
Помогает ли экранирование скобок? - не пробовал, но в коде C# запрещает их экранировать
Вопрос:
Что делать в таком случае?
UPD:
Вот на этой платформе , а также на  данной машине ошибка не возникает. Можно предположить что эта ошибка зависит от "Бог знает чего".
Я остановился на предположении, что зависит от кодировки. Вот по сообщению ошибки требуется ASCII, хотя вроде как по умолчанию UTF16. Почему там именно такая кодировка требуется - я не знаю. Может это не правильная ошибка вовсе. Устал тыкать дебаггер. Если кому интересно - можете сами поковырять.


«повторное форматирование» — что-то я очень сильно подозреваю, что вот это и является настоящей проблемой, которую надо каким-то образом устранять, а всё остальное лишь следствие

Да, я просто долго не мог понять в чем дело)) Вот и решил сюда создать в виде вопроса - может кому пригодиться. Тут запрещено просто мануалы писать, решил так попробовать

Нет никаких проблем с фигурными скобками и не может быть. Ни при использовании форматирования, ни при использовании интерполяции. https://dotnetfiddle.net/FbbPM6

Вы продолжаете изобретать собственное логирование? Вот зачем??

Я не продолжаю. Я поддерживаю и пытаюсь рефакторить. Но я же не супермен сделать все сразу

Ну то есть прав andreymal.

Кстати, тут работает: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ObeGWN
Может я что не правильно сделал? или это зависит от операционной системы?
Слыхал что есть проблема со знаками разными (типа новая строка, и т.д)

Перегрузите метод, сделав перегрузу без форматирования.
Например, так:
static void outMessage(LogFilter type, LogLevel level, string text)
{
    Logger logger = GetLoggerByType(type);
    logger.write(new LogMessage(level, type, text));
}

Если нет возможности отказаться от форматирования (скажем, оно закопано слишком глубоко) - можно принимать FormattableString:
static void outMessage(LogFilter type, LogLevel level, FormattableString text)
{
    outMessage(type, level, text.Format, text.GetArguments());
}


Изменить метод, например вот так:
static void outMessage(LogFilter type, LogLevel level, string text, params object[] args)
{
    Logger logger = GetLoggerByType(type);

    string result = args.Length > 0 ? string.Format(text, args) : text;

    logger.write(new LogMessage(level, type, result));
}

